# Assigning "let" a value in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I was playing around in Chrome devtools and tried the following code:

```js
let = 1;
let x = 2;

console.log(let); // 1
console.log(x); // 2
```

The code above won't work if I replace "let" with "var".

I'm assuming that `let = 1` is the same as `var let = 1`. If so, shouldn't `let x = 2` be translated to `1 x = 2` and therefore be an error?

Comment: `let` is keyword, you shouldn't be naming (or attempting to name) variables that. I'm surprised Chrome even let (lol) you do that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I'm assuming that `let = 1` is the same as `var let = 1`

It declares a variable, but is **not** the same. The major distinction here is that by omitting a declaration like `var`, `let`, or `const`, you're declaring this variable **globally*** (assuming you're not setting a previously-declared variable). This is what's known as an *implicit global* - a notorious [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell).

<sup>*In most cases, "global" would refer to the `window` object, but this isn't always the case. For example, Node.js has its own `global` namespace object that refers to the current module.</sup>

---

> If so, shouldn't `let x = 2` be translated to `1 x = 2` and therefore be an error?

No. `let = 1` does not override the native functionality of the `let` declaration/keyword. You've merely created a global variable of the same name. (*Perhaps it goes without saying, but don't do this!*)

---

And you didn't ask this specifically, but worth addressing:

> Why am I allowed to do `let = 1` but not `var = 1`?

`var` is a [reserved keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Keywords).

`let` is a *future* reserved keyword, which means that currently it's only reserved in **strict mode**. That in mind, if you're trying to write code that will withstand the test of time, best not use `let` as an identifier. As MDN states in the linked article, I'd imagine it'll be a reserved word sooner than later.

Comment: Great explanation, thank you very much! I wasn't aware of different types of keywords.

Answer (score 5):

Backwards compability. `let` is relatively new, therefore it is not a reserved keyword to not break old scripts using it as a variable name. That's why you can use `let` as a variable name and not `var`.

> I'm assuming that let = 1 is the same as var let = 1.

No. It rather equals `someothername = 1` and creates an *implicit global variable* which is very bad.